# How to initialize custom QQuickItem in Qt

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

I have implemented custom `QQuickItem` which is exposed to `QML`. Now it becomes more useful item in all platforms but due some reasons in Windows we are not using `QML` it's pure QT Application.

But I am not able to instantiate custom `QQuickItem` in `Qt`, could some one help me out of this?

Here is the code:
**customItem.h**

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQuickWindow>

class CustomItem : public QQuickItem
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit CustomItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
void paint();

private slots:
void handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow * win);

};
```

**customItem.cpp**:

```
#include "customItem.h"

CustomItem::CustomItem(QQuickItem *parent) :
QQuickItem(parent)
{
connect(this, &CustomItem::windowChanged, this, &CustomItem::handleWindowChanged);
}

void CustomItem::paint()
{
QQuickWindow * win = window();
qreal ratio = win->devicePixelRatio();
int w = int(ratio * win->width());
int h = int(ratio * win->height());
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

}

void CustomItem::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow * win)
{
if (win) {
connect(win, &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, this, &CustomItem::paint, Qt::DirectConnection);
    win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
}

}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView  *view = new QQuickView ();
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view);

    CustomItem *customitem = new CustomItem();///how can i set it view 
    container->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**Issue:**
Not able to instantiate CustomItem

Comment: You need to qmlRegisterType() (google it)

Comment: Wait. Never mind. You do what? You can't use a widget as a parent for a quickitem. You need to create a QuickView or a QuickWindow

Comment: @Teimpz I have updated my code, Could you help me set customItem to view.

Comment: Wel, there are more than one way. I guess the most common would be to creat a .qml file and set it as source to you quickview. Then instanciate the CustomItem from qml. (Somrthing like "CustomItem{anchors.fill:parent}". You will need to have qmlRegisterType'd the CustomItem to do this.